# Java: Generic collection for holding primitives of different types

Tags: java, generics, collections

This may be a stupid question, but is there a type of collection in Java that will hold primitives of varying type? I'm currently creating a method that formats two types of objects, and I'm attempting to store the parameters in arrays as a means of avoiding a method with ten+ parameters, instead using two arrays to hold the values and pass them in instead.

The types will be a combination of Strings, ints and booleans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primitives in Java can be boxed into objects. The type `Object` can hold values of type `String`, `int`, and `boolean`, by storing primitive `int` values as `Integer` objects, and primitive `boolean` values as `Boolean` objects. This can often be done implicity, without the programmer explicitly wrapping or unwrapping them, which is called auto-boxing.

Thus, any collection or array that holds values of type `Object`, such as `Object[]`, `List<Object>`, etc., can hold your values.

For example:

```
Object[] array = new Object[] { 1, 2, true, "hi" };

List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
list.add(5);
list.add(false);
list.add("test");
```

For variable arguments to a method, just use `Object...`:

```
void myMethod(Object... params) {
  // ...
}
```

When you process your array or collection of `Object` values, you can use `instanceof` and casts to find the types and handle them correctly.

## Warning

When autoboxing to type `Object`, primitives are boxed into `Object` values directly. In the following code:

```
short shortValue = 0;
int myPrimitive = shortValue;
Object myObject = shortValue;
```

`myPrimitive` is of type `int`, but `myObject` is of type `Short`. You asked for an `Object`, and you got one! Be careful of what you assume about an object of type `Object`, because in principle you can't assume anything other than it is an `Object`.

Luckily, you don't always have to check an `Object` for every primitive number type. In most cases, it's enough to cast it to a `Number`, and then use for example `.intValue()` to get a value of type int. That is to say, code like this:

```
double x = 2.3;
Object o = x;
int i = ((Number) o).intValue();
```

is equivalent to this:

```
double x = 2.3;
int i = (int) x;
```

Comment: This solution suites my needs at present, Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The only "collection" that can hold integers in Java is an array, and it can only hold primitives of a single type.

If you need to collect primitives of multiple types, you can create a class that has multiple primitive members, and then use any Collection you want to store multiple instances of this class.

Comment: Would it be worthwhile using an array of objects, then getting the primitive from each object in the array?

Comment: @jbailie1991 Worthwhile in what way?

Comment: Well as opposed to creating a class with multiple primitive members, for the sake of saving time spent coding such a class

Comment: @jbailie1991 Advantages could be type safety and code readability, if you have a long list of parameters and each parameter has its own name and type.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you really need such a collection where you want to avoid the costs of boxing for values, you can implement such a collection by yourself quite easily by piggy backing on an already implemented primitive collection [such as Trove](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/package-summary.html). As you did not specify what type of collection you require, let us look at an example map that maps primitive integers to the values you named:

```
class PrimitiveMap {

  final TIntBooleanMap booleans;
  final TIntIntMap ints;
  final TIntObjectMap<String> strings;

  // Constructor omitted

  void putBoolean(int index, boolean value) {
    removeIndex(index);
    booleans.put(index, value);
  }

  boolean getBoolean(int index) {
    booleans.get(index);
  }

  // similarly for the other collection types

  private removeIndex(int index) {
    booleans.remove(index);
    ints.remove(index);
    strings.remove(index);
  }
}
```

An obvious down side is that you need to *remember* the type of element that is inserted. Alternatively, you can used boxed-values when accessing your collection where you however resolve the box before storing your value:

```
public void put(Object value) {
  if(value instanceof Boolean) {
    putBoolean((Boolean) value);
  } else if(value instanceof Integer) {
    putInteger((Integer) value);
  } else if(value instanceof String) {
    putString((String) value);
  }
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal value = " + value);
} 

public Object get(int index) {
  boolean booleanValue = booleans.get(index);
  if(booleanValue != booleans.getNoEntryValue()) {
    return booleanValue;
  }
  int intValue = ints.get(index);
  if(intValue != ints.getNoEntryValue()) {
    return intValue;
  }
  String stringValue = strings.get(index);
  if(stringValue != null) {
    return stringValue;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Note that this approach only pays off if you are really trying to optimize your memory footprint as you avoid the overhead of keeping references to boxing objects. I assume that you need to maintain huge collections in order to measure a difference. Be sure to check your application's footprint before implementing such a collection.

This approach works similarly for lists where the implementation would also be backed by a map for each primitive type, only the access API would be different. For sets, you can do something similar where you back-up each primitive collection by a `TXXXSet`.

Comment: I do like this approach, But I'm under a very tight deadline, so I'm going to go with Dan Getz's solution. Good answer and explanation though